# Get the facebook post likes on a given date

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm working with facebook graph API and i need to get the number of likes a given post had on a given date. As in, how many likes the post had on Jan 20, but i can't find a way to do that. I already tried with /POST_ID/likes and i get the people who liked the post, but not a single date, also tried using ?since=DATE&until=DATE but no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't possible using the Graph API, you can only get the "current" total number of likes  for a post.

You could set up some cron jobs and a service within your application to get the current amount of likes everyday for the lifetime of the post, and store them locally. And then do some math on your local data to figure out how many likes were actually done between a date range. Probably not ideal, or even practical, and in your case you probably would be missing a lot of data since you don't already have this set up.